# Applying style to DatePicker calendarStyle Property failes (WPF)

Tags: wpf, datepicker, custom-controls, wpf-style

I am trying to create a custom date picker. I have created a WPF custom control Library. Renamed the control and changed the override meta data to the following.

```
public class SeasonDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    static SeasonDatePicker()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SeasonDatePicker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SeasonDatePicker)));
    }
}
```

After this i started to work out the template in the Generic.xaml file. First i was working with static resources to refer to the different styles (one style for Calandar and one for CalandarItem). researching the web i was able to find that it is not possible to define multiple resource in the Generic.xaml file.
So i changed to inline styles but still the change is not visible.

When i did the same thing in a WPF application it al worked. So i am at a loss right now.

The full Generic.xaml file is to big to post here but i have uploaded it: [Generic.xaml](http://1drv.ms/1ZCB3GU)

Since i am pretty new to WPF and styling any help would be appreciated.